# Как прекратить работу класса в его методе?

Tags: ооп, php

Есть такой класс:

```
class Auth {
public $login;
public $password;
public $remember;
public $error;
public $sucess;

function Auth($login, $password, $rem){
$this->login = poid($login);
$this->password = poid($password);
$this->remember = poid($rem);
$this->TestIssetUser();
$this->GoUser();
}
function TestIssetUser(){
//....
}
//....
}
```

Можно ли в методе TestIssetUser вырубить дальнейшую работу конструктора? Т.е. типа exit, но вырубал чтобы не весь скрипт, а только конструктор класса Auth.

Comment: вернитесь из функции

    if (!$this->TestIssetUser()) return false

конструктор прервать нельзя :) он же не параллельно выполняется (я здесь вообще конструктора не вижу)

Comment: Ну метод Auth и есть конструктор. Жалко, что прервать его нельзя. Ну значит буду действовать как обычно.

Comment: метод Auth - это метод.

конструктор выглядит так

   function __constructor() {
   }

из любого метода можно вернуться, что значит прервать ?

Comment: Конструктор, на сколько я знаю, это метод, который вызывается при создании объекта класса. Ну я уже понял, что нельзя прервать его.

Comment: и как вы создаете этот элемент класса, что у вас вызывается Auth() ? в вашем примере - конструктор пустой. а Auth - инициализирующий метод, есть очень большая разница. еще раз - **прервать метод значит  вернуться из него**, exit - завершить процесс.

Comment: > и как вы создаете этот элемент класса,
> что у вас вызывается Auth()

Кажется, человек пререшёл на php послед другого ЯП. например с java :)  
Там конструктор это метод название которого совпадает с названием класса

Comment: Да и на php вроде раньше так было.. ))

Comment: @stasQa я не застал эти славные времена )

Comment: Спасибо за ценную информацию)

Comment: @zenith, застали:

> В целях обратной совместимости, если PHP 5 не может обнаружить объявленный метод __construct(), вызов конструктора произойдет по прежней схеме, через обращение к методу, имя которого соответствует имени класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызывайте метод GoUser()  в средине метода TestIssetUser(), если все впорядке